# How to search a date field using wild cards?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a date search field in my ASP.Net application where the user enters the date he's looking for and the SQL query looks for the exact date provided.

I'm asked to allow the user to enter the date search using wildcards as follows:
- `*/12/2015` would mean get all the month of December, 2015
- `*/*/2015` would mean get all the year of 2015
- `*/*/*` would mean get all the data you got

The only way I could think about to do this is to look in my C# code for '*' in the date, if it exists I will replace the query by a date range based on the position of the `*`.

This solution doesn't look practical to me, is there an easier way to do it in C# or SQL ?

Comment: "An easier way" isn't really a question. What part specifically do you need help with? Take a look at [DATEPART()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: in given situation i would parse date search string to get day, month and year as integer (in c#) and then search by 3 integer parameters in sql (i assume that type of date column is datetime, not varchar)

Comment: It seems that parse and search with range is good solution. If you have index on the date field then range condition will use it. If you start casting there can be perffomance issues.
BTW, what data type is used to store date in DB? And is there many rows in table?

Comment: Out of curiousity, would something `*/12/*` (december of any year) be allowed too? Otherwise I'd translate the parsed values to ranges and use `between` for better performance (depending on your indices). Using year() and month() might change your query plan into an index scan instead of a seek. Sorry @kiryl, cross post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as you already suggested and parse the search-string. Then depending on the search-string you can select your data. However you do not have to create dateranges, you can use [YEAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186313.aspx) and [MONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187813.aspx) isntead.

Your SQL-Query could look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YEAR(YourDate) = 2015 and MONTH(YourDate) = 12
```

Comment: If 'YourDate' is indexed field then such query can't use it. It can hit performance.

Answer (score 2):

the solution you found is the only one that makes sense while properly handling the information.

what you've been asked for is to give the users 'something' that allows them to search the dates as text and imho there are 2 possible solution:

- the one you found (imho the 'right' one)
- store the date as formatted string (BAD, AVOID, NIGHTMARE)

the wildcard approach would be simple to implement should you (wrongly, badly, poorly) store the date information and the format in a text field but this would prevent you from manipulating any date as a date and will put you in huge troubles at the first request that involves date handling (consolidation by month, calculate any rate in a given time span, etc...) or if you happen to have users in different countries (that expect a format different from the one stored into the text field).

implementing the search logic in the frontend the database will store the information using the correct data type and all the manipulation needed to accomplish the 'search the date as text' task are performed by the frontend that will feed to the RDBMS a set of parameters that allows it to handle the date properly.

the result would be as follows:
`*/12/2015` --> `between '20151201' and '20151231'`
`*/*/2015` --> `between '20150101' and '20151231'`
`*/*/*` --> no filter at all

if stored procedures are in use instead the result would be a couple of date parameters filled with the date values.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can replace `*` with `%` and use `LIKE`. Here is one example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (
    SELECT cast('20150611' as date) as dateColumn
    UNION
    SELECT cast('20150610' as date)) as X
WHERE convert(varchar, dateColumn, 103) LIKE N'%/06/2015'
```

Keep in mind that this is practical and not the best solution from performance point of view.